# non-split extension of the simple group $L_3(4)$

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups, group-extensions, groups-of-lie-type

I would like to know the structure of the groups $L_3(4).C_2$ and $L_3(4).C_{11}$.

(By $C_n$ I mean the cyclic group  of order $n$ and by $G=K.L$ I mean the non-spli extension of $K$ by $L$, were $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.)

Comment: I have never seen the notation $\;L_3(4)\;$ in group theory...definition?

Comment: @Tina there is no nonsplit extension of $L_3(4)$ by $C_{11}$. $|L_3(4)|$ is not divisible by 11, so Schur-Zassenhaus shows the extension splits.

Comment: $L_3(4)=PSL(3,4)$

Comment: Dear Jack, thank you very much. You are absolutely right! But is there any hints for the group $L_3(4).C_2$?

Comment: It appears there are no nonsplit extensions of the normal L3(4) by C2 either.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there are no nonsplit extensions of $L_3(4)$ by $C_{11}$ or $C_2$.

*(This CW answer posted to remove this question from the unanswered queue.  All credit to Jack Schmidt in the comments.)*